# Create Session Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

While writing tests for my routes in NodeJS.I want to create a session for my request and set userId and useragent.

I have written the test:

```
describe('\nTesting\n', () => {
it('responds with valid HTTP status, status, code & data', async function () {
    const response = await agent.post('/address').set('User-Agent', 'test').set('userId', '1');
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    expect(response.body.status).to.equal(1);
    expect(response.body.code).to.equal(200);
    expect(response.body).to.be.an('object');
});
```

I have to set userId and userAgent but implementing it this way is resulting in an error 401.
Here agent = supertest.agent(app);

Comment: Show the controller code, how did you do the authentication?